# How to run and manage multiple instances of an application (different start params) on multiple servers?

Tags: design, architecture, deployment, docker

Our main (C#) application:

- takes in parameters and starts working (batch processing, takes anywhere from minutes to hours)
- up to x instances of said application per server
- instances are started by users from our front end by making a request to a "master" on a server (really bad load balancing is just one of the problems).

The application itself is really simple. The instances themselves are "stateless", meaning it doesn't really matter if they do fail as long as they are being restarted with the same parameters. The application is also pretty lightweight.

Problems:

- **deployment of the main application is done manually**, by literally uploading it to servers and changing the application path the "master" uses to launch the instances
- if an instance errors for whatever reason, healthchecks fail and the database entry for the instance is being deleted -> users need to manually restart the application since **our backend isn't capable of restarting the instance** on another server.

A dream would be having a single endpoint on to which we pass the starting parameters, and a framework (or whatever) takes care of the actual provisioning and error handling. Maybe restarting an instance automatically on another server if one should decide to spontaneously fail.

Docker came to our minds, but we thought this would only really help us in terms of deployment.

**A push in to the right direction would be wonderful!**

Comment: Asking for tools is off-topic because it attracts opinionated answers.

Comment: @RikD: I would not read this as a request for a software recommendation, this is more like a request for an architectural approach (which might be supported by a class of tools or procedures, not necessarily by a specific tool). Unfortunately, our community here often does  "buzz word" closing - if there is the slightest sign a question can be interpreted as a software recommendation request, the question gets downvotes and close votes, regardless if it is a good question which would otherwise be on-topic.

Comment: I agree Doc, someone voted to close though (not me) and the title specifically asked for tool recommendation. Your edit solves that.

Comment: Said that, I think it could make sense to make a pure software recommendation request of it and ask a related question on softwarerecommendations.stackexchange, specififically for a management tool or framework for distributed computing. If you decide to do so, you will have to add some more specific information (like operating systems required, ~number of servers to support, more specific requirements for the frontend, your budget) etc.

Comment: @DocBrown Right, I wasn't really aware that software recommendation requests weren't allowed. And yes, my search wasn't just for a tool but more a general architectural approach which might be supported by some sort of tools. Thanks for your understanding and the edit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your application from a console app that takes parameters and is started per job to a service that runs constantly listens to a message queue.

Run instances in the cloud so that you are able to dynamically spin up new instances via the cloud providers API.

Your architecture then works as follows

- Users click button in UI specifying input parameters.
- Message with the parameters is sent to the message queue
- Worker applications listen to queue and pick up the new message
- If worker crashes mid processing the MQ software itself will manage re-queuing the - - message so its picked up by another server.
- On successful completion the worker posts a message to a second queue with the - results, which can then be saved to a db, email to the user, whatever

To manage scaling, have a second app keep track of the number of messages in the queue and the number of avaialble workers. If jobs arent being done fast enough have it call the clouds API to spin up a new VM with your service installed. As the service runs continually this will immediately pick up a new job from the queue without having to send it parameters, change master directories etc

Essentially here you are using the out of the box Message Queue (RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ, Cloud offering of your choice) functionality to do the fiddly orchestration of your applications.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This is exactly what I was looking for and the architecture as you described is precisely what I had in mind but somehow just couldn't figure out!

Comment: Instead of changing the CLI application, wouldn't it it be an sensible alternative to add a dispatcher service which does the message queue handling and starts the existing CLI as instances in a separate process? This service could be implemented very generic, so I am wondering if there isn't such a piece of software already available somewhere, some "generic message queue adapter" for CLI applications.

Comment: I have seen systems like that where the software you want to launch is third party (excel), the trouble is getting the feedback if they crash or hang